# Auto number table rows meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I made data collection which is presented by the package `aslagle:reactive-table`.
Is there a possibility that each record could take automatic numeration like this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/4WHpr/1/)

and that the continuity of numbering would be preserved despite the removal of one of the records in table?

Answer (score 1):

Take the collection/object that you pass into `reactive-table`. Transform it with a template helper so that it has an added 'cell' for the numbering. Pass the transformed object into `reactive-table`. Because template helpers are reactive, a new transformed object gets returned every time the initial collection changes.

I hope that I understood your correctly, and that this helps.